# Is gov.uk a tld or a domain?

Tags: python, url, dns, urllib, tld

### Background

Running this snippet of code in python's interpreter, we get an IP address for `gov.uk`.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('gov.uk')
'151.101.64.144'
```

gov.uk is a TLD according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk) and the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/). Similar TLDs that are also domains include `gov.au`, `gov.br`, and `s3.amazonaws.com`.

In trying to answer this question with python, I tried using urlparse, but I just get a domain blob:

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://gov.uk')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='gov.uk', 
    path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Using tldextract, it looks like there's no domain or subdomain.

```py
>>> import tldextract
>>> tldextract.extract('https://gov.uk')
ExtractResult(subdomain='', domain='', suffix='gov.uk')
```

### Question

For `https://gov.uk`, which part is the domain and which part is the TLD?

Comment: The wikipedia page you link to explicitely lists `.gov.uk' in the "Second-level domains" part of the article.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Should the result of
`tldextract.extract('https://gov.uk')` be `ExtractResult(subdomain='', domain='gov', suffix='uk')`? If this is the case, it is a point that many tools, including tldextract are confused on.

Comment: There is no confusion to have. All domains are subdomains and hence all subdomains are also domains, this is all related to from where you look at things so it all depends on WHY you need to do this extract and what you do later with those results/parts. Use the terminology at https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-miscellaneous it is clear. `gov.uk` is a public suffix (even if registration under it is certainly not so public), it is a better term than `eTLD` or "effective TLD". One has to understand there are 2 facets: the resolution part (here all are domains) and the registration part.

Comment: If you want the TLD, with its strict definition, there is only one, the string after the last dot, so `uk` here. But it may not be useful for what you need to do, hence the public suffix is maybe more interesting, which is `gov.uk`. Things like that have consequences when searching for administrative boundaries. domain and subdomain terms should be avoided in this context as they do not help at all. suffix also. There is either a public suffix or a TLD, not a "suffix" or "extension", that doesn't exist.

Comment: Given that you have 2 long consecutive comments, it seems like you want to post an answer instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gov.uk`, like `.uk`, is an **Effective TLD** or eTLD.

I picked this up from the go package [public suffix](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix) and the wikipedia page for [Public Suffix List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List).

Mozilla created the Public Suffix List, which is now managed by https://publicsuffix.org/list/. It can be found in [Mozilla's Documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List), but this term does not appear anywhere on https://publicsuffix.org/list/ at the time of writing.

Comment: This nuance with eTLDs is sort of implied in the [read.me for tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract#readme) (esp. with examples like `bbc.co.uk`), but it would certainly help if it was made more explicit.

Comment: Documentation that has "nuance that is sort of implied" is documentation that needs improvement. I'll post an issue.

Comment: Posted issue here: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/issues/234